# Recyclerview only load Image when itemview is shown

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I would like to load images in my itemviews of my recyclerview but only if the itemview is shown.
I tried something like this in my adapter so far:

```
if (holder.itemView.isShown()) {
            Log.e("SHOWn", "yes " + position);
        }
        if (holder.itemView.isFocused()) {
            Log.e("FOCUSED", "yes " + position);
        }
        if (holder.itemView.hasFocus()) {
            Log.e("HASFOCUS", "yes " + position);
        }
```

and I tried in my fragment to add a onScrollListener to the recylcerview:

```
recyclerViewSearchGif.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
```

But I don't know how to use it for my case.
To sum up, I would like to detect the current visible item in the recyclerview while the user scrolled in it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say load images, do you mean load images from network?

You should just load/bind the appropriate images in `RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder` in your recyclerview's adapter, that's the callback for when an item is shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to load images in my itemviews of my recyclerview but only if the itemview is shown.

During the execution of onBindViewHolder() method, a fixed/certain amount of views will be generated by recyclerview to show your items/images...  And after scrolling down/up, onBindViewHolder() will be called again to generate respective views.